# PHP-сайт на RDP

Tags: php, rdp, windows-server-2012

На сервере (подключаюсь через RDP) запущен веб-сайт.
Запускаю строкой `php artisan serve --host ***.***.***.*** --port 80 -vv`

Пока сессия RDP активна он работает. Когда отключаюсь, несмотря на то что идет сообщение о том что все ПО останется активным, доступ на сайт перестает работать.

На сервере Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Строка запускается из под пользователя, который выходит после закрытия удаленной сессии.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Не используйте "выход из системы" просто закройте окно терминала (сервер терминала должен быть настроен на продолжение работы отключенного сеанса)

Вариант 2. Сделайте задачу в планировщике. Настройте имя и пароль учетки, от которой будет запускаться. Установите параметр "Выполнять для всех пользователей". Если нужна постоянная работа, то поставьте триггер "при запуске системы". Если нужен ручной запуск, то через терминал будете в планировщике правой кнопки мыши запускать задачу